# GIT Codebase Checkout

Tags: git

Suppose, there is a commit for a project version (say version 1.1) on 10.03.2016 and another commit for the version (say version 1.2). Now when i'm performing codebase checkout for the projects latest version for 1.2, the whole project is getting downloaded on the current date (say 18.04.2016). So if some 'lib' files getting changed or not, those can't be uniquely identified; rather the whole content is found to be different till i now manually where the differentiation lies. I want to know any way to identify uniquely which files are changed from one version to other?

Comment: Can you please clarify the question? maybe explain the problem in a bit more detail?

Comment: version ? using another branch ? how it is differentiated between versions ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand. If you want to see what changed between versions, use the `git log` or `git diff` commands. You can also use one of the available history browsers (`gitk`, `gitg`, etc.) to visualize the history and make browsing possible using your mouse.

Comment: If in version, say 1.1 has three jars (say A.jar, B.jar, C.jar) in the lib and in version 1.2 there are four jars (say A.jar, B.jar, C.jar, D.jar) in it's lib. Now A.jar and B.jar have no changes in both of the version, whereas in C.jar some changes took place in the version 1.2; D.jar is an entirely new jar added in the lib of version 1.2. So now how shall I be able to derive the changes in the jars committed in the latest version (i.e. in version 1.2)?

Comment: Unpack the jars and compare? Git can only show the textual difference between text files (or directories)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `git diff --name-only 1.1 1.2`, which gives you the list of files modified from version 1.1 to version 1.2 (assuming there are tags named 1.1 and 1.2, use the commit identifier if it is not the case).

If this isn't what you're looking for, please clarify the question.

Comment: What I meant is provided jar names say C.jar in lib is same in both the versions but some contents are changed or added in the latest version in the C.jar in lib. So now how can i able to derive that in the latest version the C.jar in lib has undergone some changes ?

Comment: What I meant is provided jar names say C.jar in lib is same in both the versions but some contents are changed or added in the latest version in the C.jar in lib. So now how can i able to derive that in the latest version the C.jar in lib has undergone some changes ?